# Docker set read timeout for push

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

Whenever I push larger docker images I get a read timeout. 
When I try to push again, I get "is already in progress" message.

I use docker-machine on osx (virtualbox).

This leads me to believe that the image is pushing in the background, but my connection to my VM has timed out. This seems to be on larger images only.

**How does one set the read timeout for the linux command line docker client?**

```
docker push repository.com/thing
Image f7a77fb0b14d already pushed, skipping
Image 01e40c794f94 already pushed, skipping
Image 7547e52aac4b already pushed, skipping
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='192.168.99.101', port=2376): Read timed out.

docker push repository.com/thing
Sending image list
push repository.com/thing is already in progress
```